# how to check which div is active to pass session values

Tags: asp.net

I am having `log_in` page. On that page I have created 2 `<div>` one for log_in user and another to register new candidate.I have to check the `candidate ID` to allow access to pages.For that I have to check candidate is doing log_in or registering,so for this I have to check which div is active.For that i have given id's to div and `run at="server"` property.

I don't know how to check active  in code-behind.And I also want to create session which hold `candidate ID`.So in another pages I can check `ID` for further operations.

Answer (score 1):

Just create 2 buttons with `runat=server` and check which one has been clicked with server side onclick method. Depending on which gets called, validate and then log in or register user.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS class on clicking the Div, using Jquery, and in Code behind you can check its class

Answer (score 0):

You can check the visibility status of the 2 `<div>` elements. The visible one is the active div.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create two forms on the page? One for logging in, one for registering.

Comment: Not if it's WebForms! But he could create 2 buttons and check which one has been clicked